# Не ставится gatsbyjs в ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, gatsbyjs

Хочу создать простейший блог на гедсби делаю по этому видио https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlE4o4K7HLY

`npm install -g gatsby-cli` установлен

не получается запустить гедсби ;_;

```
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ gatsby new gatsby-blog https://github.com/ImedAdel/gatsby-london
gatsby: команда не найдена
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ npm gatsby new gatsby-blog https://github.com/ImedAdel/gatsby-london
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/comp/javaScript/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/comp/javaScript/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/comp/.npm/_logs/2021-07-18T15_51_21_548Z-debug.log
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ node -v
v16.5.0
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ npm -v
7.19.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался надо было после `нвм` установить `гедсби`

```
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ nvm install 16.0
Downloading and installing node v16.0.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.0.0/node-v16.0.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################### 100,0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v16.0.0 (npm v7.10.0)
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ gatsby new gatsby-london https://github.com/ImedAdel/gatsby-london
gatsby: команда не найдена
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ nvm list
       v10.24.1
       v12.13.0
->      v16.0.0
        v16.5.0
default -> 16.5.0 (-> v16.5.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v16.5.0) (default)
stable -> 16.5 (-> v16.5.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1
lts/erbium -> v12.22.3 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.17.3 (-> N/A)
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ npm install -g gatsby-cli
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'

added 572 packages, and audited 573 packages in 31s

113 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

4 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$ gatsby new gatsby-london https://github.com/ImedAdel/gatsby-london
info Creating new site from git: https://github.com/ImedAdel/gatsby-london.git

Клонирование в «gatsby-london»…
remote: Enumerating objects: 111, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (111/111), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (107/107), done.
remote: Total 111 (delta 0), reused 97 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
success Created starter directory layout
info Installing packages...
info Preferred package manager set to "npm"

npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated @types/vfile-message@2.0.0: This is a stub types definition. vfile-message provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@2.2.1: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated gatsby-image@2.11.0: This package has been deprecated in favor of gatsby-plugin-image. The migration guide can be found here: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 2641 packages, and audited 2642 packages in 4m

229 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

40 vulnerabilities (30 moderate, 10 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

info Initialising git in gatsby-london

Инициализирован пустой репозиторий Git в /home/comp/javaScript/gatsby-london/.giinfo Create initial git commit in gatsby-london


*** Пожалуйста, скажите мне кто вы есть.

Запустите

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Ваше Имя"

для указания идентификационных данных аккаунта по умолчанию.
Пропустите параметр --global для указания данных только для этого репозитория.

fatal: не удалось выполнить автоопределение адреса электронной почты (получено «info Initial git commit failed - removing git support

info
Your new Gatsby site has been successfully bootstrapped. Start developing it by
running:

  cd gatsby-london
  gatsby develop


(base) comp@comp:~/javaScript$
```

Comment: nvm use 16.0 надо нажать